# Luigid Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-asyncio, luigi

I am trying to use luigi in the central-scheduler mode. Whenever i try to run the central scheduler by using the command

```
$ luigid
```

It returns a syntax error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


 File "/usr/local/bin/luigid", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('luigi==2.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'luigid')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/luigi-2.1.1-py2.7.egg/luigi/cmdline.py", line 15, in luigid
    import luigi.server
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/luigi-2.1.1-py2.7.egg/luigi/server.py", line 51, in <module>
    import tornado.httpserver
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/http1connection.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tornado import gen
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1236, in <module>
    import tornado.platform.asyncio
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 33, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asyncio/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import selectors
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/asyncio/selectors.py", line 39
    "{!r}".format(fileobj)) from None
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're not supposed to have `asyncio` in your python 2 path (it requires python 3.3 or later). You could try `pip uninstall asyncio`.

Comment: but it is importing asyncio, so shouldn't I have it in my path ?

Comment: It [tries](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/platform/asyncio.py#L33) to import asyncio actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know why, but downgrading tornado does the job.

```
  $ sudo pip install tornado==4.1
  $ luigid
  Defaulting to basic logging; consider specifying logging_conf_file in luigi.cfg.
  2016-06-20 14:52:02,038 luigi.scheduler[5400] INFO: No prior state file exists at /var/lib/lui
  ......
```

Comment: If you follow @Vincent's link above, as of version 3.2 [Tornado will try to import asyncio](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/a48f65a42c3b3f0f2b21bcbce4da12c2d4419915/tornado/gen.py#L1231-1245). If it succeeds, it will use it. If it's not there, it moves on. Either downgrade Tornado as you did, or uninstall asyncio as was suggested. The latter is the better route.